# CSS-How to make sidebar overlap the footer?

Tags: html, css

I want my sidebar to overlap the footer. I tried *position:absolute*, but that didn't work.

```
.sidebar-menu {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

element.style {
padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.main-footer {
background: #fff;
padding: 15px;
color: #444;
border-top: 1px solid #d2d6de;
}
```

Comment: Where is the HTML? Please reproduce the problem in an example.

Comment: Post your html code please

Comment: Without the HTML code is hard to get a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you should try use z-index attribute. If you set sidebar bigger z-index it will overlap your footer.

Comment: I think you unterstand my question correctly. Although it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
.sidebar-menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

Hope this helps.